# Combinatorial Circuit

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm trying to learn more about logical statement. I have this question:
(q --> -p) --> r. Im supposed to create a combinatorial circuit out of this statement. What i did was to convert the logical statement to something easier. So i got:
 $(q \rightarrow -p ) \rightarrow r$ ... $(-q \cup  -p ) \rightarrow r$...$-(-q \cup  -p ) \cup  r$ and then i got $(q \cup  p ) \cup  r
$

Im really not sure if this is correct, could anyone please check and correct if I did anything wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are the unions supposed to be $\lor$? This doesn’t look quite right, as $q=T, p=F, r=F$ satisfies the second expression but not the first.

Comment: Does the minus sign mean $\lnot?$  You can use `\lnot` for $\lnot$ `\vee` for $\vee$

Comment: Yes it does mean that! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until the last step, your reasoning works. However, we have to use De Morgan’s law to distribute negation over conjunction/disjunction. Instead, we would get:
$$
\neg (\neg q \lor \neg p) \lor r \equiv (q \land p) \lor r
$$

Comment: Okay thanks for the help!!

Comment: Just another question, was it right for me to convert the original statement if I wanted to create a combinatorial circuit?

Comment: Depending on what gates you can use, it is probably the most straightforward way to handle this one.